# Validating text inputs in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, validation

My code doesn't work, can you point out whats wrong. I am trying to validate user input in SNameInput, error label should change it's text when the input is not valid and STitle should change it's text when user is done typing in SNameInput and it is valid, thanks!

```
func textFieldDidChange(SNameInput: UITextField) {
        let d = ""
        if (SNameInput.isEqual(d)||(SNameInput.text?.characters.count)! >= 21) {
            errorLabel.text = "Name has to be a t least 1 character and not longer than 20"}
        else{  errorLabel.text = ""
            Stitle.text = SNameInput.text}
    }
```

Comment: Did you set textfield delegate to `self`?

Comment: is your delegate method called??

Comment: You have strange expressions like (SNameInput: UITextField) SNameInput.isEqual(d).  Also, your English sentences are very difficult to understand since you don't end each sentence with the period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibility: you didn't add `editingDidEnd` action to your `SNameInput` text field.

> `editingDidEnd`: A touch ending an editing session in a `UITextField`
>   object by leaving its bounds.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SNameInput.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
}

@IBAction func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
    guard let string = sender.text else { return }

    if (string.isEmpty || string.characters.count >= 21) {
        errorLabel.text = "Name has to be a t least 1 character and not longer than 20"
    }
    else{
        errorLabel.text = ""
        Stitle.text = string
    }
}
```